# Is this a compiler trick in Go?

Tags: go

There is a function in the Go language (https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/io/ioutil/ioutil.go#L18-L38). Specifically this branch seems redundant to me:

```
if int64(int(capacity)) == capacity {
    buf.Grow(int(capacity))
}
```

`capacity` is never modified and the function doesn't seem to be recursive. Is this something to trick the compiler?

Answer (score 5):

The capacity argument to `io.ReadAll` has type `int64`.  The argument to `*bytes.Buffer`'s `Grow` is `int`.  So we have to narrow the input `int64` to (perhaps) 32 bits.  The result may not be the same value as the original `int64` value.  If not, we skip the call (though I might argue that we should try to grow the buffer to the maximum `int` value, or—probably better—just return an error directly).

Answer (score 2):

It *looks* like it is to prevent allocating a very large buffer for architectures smaller than 64 bits. That equivalence check will fail if int is smaller than 64 bits on the architecture and capacity is larger than int limit.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. If the size of `int` is less than 64 bits, the check will only fail if `capacity` is over the maximum value of `int`.

Comment: Right that was what i meant to say i will fix the answer